# Specify SSH configuration file at run time in Ansible 1.9

Tags: python, ssh, ansible

I'm managing two server environments that are configured differently.  I access the two environments by specifying different SSH configurations on the command line because I need to specify a different `User`, `ProxyCommand`, and a list of other options for SSH.

e.g.

```
ssh oldserver.example.org -F config_legacy

ssh newserver.example.org -F config
```

To configure and maintain state on my servers, I've been using Ansible (version 1.9.0.1), which reads an SSH configuration file that is specified by a line in its `ansible.cfg`:

```
...
ssh_args =  -F some_configuration_file
...
```

The `ansible.cfg` is [loaded a number of ways](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/b89071e4858e5bf37846b347fab43d95b4785aef/lib/ansible/constants.py#L67-L82:):

```
def load_config_file():
    ''' Load Config File order(first found is used): ENV, CWD, HOME, /etc/ansible '''

    p = configparser.ConfigParser()

    path0 = os.getenv("ANSIBLE_CONFIG", None)
    if path0 is not None:
        path0 = os.path.expanduser(path0)
    path1 = os.getcwd() + "/ansible.cfg"
    path2 = os.path.expanduser("~/.ansible.cfg")
    path3 = "/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg"

    for path in [path0, path1, path2, path3]:
        if path is not None and os.path.exists(path):
            try:
                p.read(path)
            except configparser.Error as e:
                print("Error reading config file: \n{0}".format(e))
                sys.exit(1)
            return p
    return None
```

I could use this behavior to set an environmental variable before each command to load an entirely different ansible.cfg, but that seems messy as I only need to fiddle the ssh_args.  Unfortunately, Ansible doesn't expose the command switch to specify an SSH config.

I'd like to not maintain any modifications to Ansible I'd like to not wrap all calls to the `ansible` or `ansible-playbook` commands.  To preserve the behavior of Ansible's commands, I believe my options are:

- a) have the target of `ssh_args =  -F <<config_file>>` be a script that's opened
- b) have the target of `p.read(path)` be a script that gets expanded to generate a valid ansible.cfg
- c) just maintain different ansible.cfg files and take advantage of the fact that Ansible picks this file in the order of environmental variable, cwd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Option C is the only way that I can see accomplishing this.  You could have your default/most-used ansible.cfg be the one that is read in the cwd ansible.cfg, then optionally setting/unsetting an environmental variable that points to the version that specifies the `ssh_args = -F config_legacy` line that you need (`ANSIBLE_SSH_ARGS`).

The reason for needing to do an ansible.cfg instead of just passing an envvar with SSH options is because Ansible does not honor the `User` setting in an ssh configuration file -- it's already decided who it wants to run as on kick off of a command.

Dynamic inventory (`ec2.py`) files are incredibly poor places to hack in a change for maintenance reasons, which is why it's typical to see `--user=REMOTE_USER` flags, which coupled with setting an `ANSIBLE_SSH_ARGS="-F some_ssh_config"` environmental variable, make for a ugly commands to give to a casual user of an Ansible repo.

e.g.

```
ANSIBLE_SSH_ARGS="-F other_ssh_config" ansible-playbook playbooks/why_i_am_doing_this.yml -u ubuntu
```

v.

```
ansible-playbook playbooks/why_i_am_doing_this.yml -F other_ansible.cfg
```

---

Option A doesn't work because the file is opened all at once for loading into Python, per the `p.read()` above, not that it matters because if files could arbitrarily decide to open as scripts, we'd be living in a very scary world.

This is how the `ansible.cfg` loading looks from a system perspective:

$ sudo dtruss -a ansible ......

```
74947/0x11eadf:    312284       3      2 stat64("/Users/tfisher/code/ansible/ansible.cfg\0", 0x7FFF55D936C0, 0x7FD70207EA00)             = 0 0
74947/0x11eadf:    312308      19     17 open_nocancel("/Users/tfisher/code/ansible/ansible.cfg\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)          = 5 0
74947/0x11eadf:    312316       3      1 read_nocancel(0x5, "# ansible.cfg \n#\n# Config-file load order is:\n#   envvar ANSIBLE_CONFIG\n#   `pwd`/ansible.cfg\n#   ~/.ansible.cfg\n#   /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg\n\n# Some unmodified settings are left as comments to encourage research/suggest modific", 0x1000)               = 3477 0
74947/0x11eadf:    312308      19     17 open_nocancel("/Users/tfisher/code/ansible/ansible.cfg\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)          = 5 0
```

Option B doesn't work for the same reasons why A doesn't work -- even if you create a mock Python file object with proper read/readline/readlines sigatures, the file is still being opened for reading only, not execution.

And if this is the correct repo for OpenSSH, the [config file is specified like so](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/51a1c2115265c6e80ede8a5c9dccada9aeed7143/pathnames.h#L38):

```
#define _PATH_HOST_CONFIG_FILE      SSHDIR "/ssh_config"
```

[processed like so](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/51a1c2115265c6e80ede8a5c9dccada9aeed7143/ssh.c#L453-L476):

```
    /* Read systemwide configuration file after user config. */
    (void)read_config_file(_PATH_HOST_CONFIG_FILE, pw,
        host, host_arg, &options,
        post_canon ? SSHCONF_POSTCANON : 0);
```

[and read here with an fopen](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/51a1c2115265c6e80ede8a5c9dccada9aeed7143/readconf.c#L1529), which leaves no room for "file as a script" schenanigans.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is set the environment variable `ANSIBLE_SSH_ARGS` to the arguments you want Ansible to pass to the ssh command.

Comment: Oof, I'm a bad person -- that's actually what I was alluding to in my self answer, but was explaining myself really poorly.  The problem with adding ANSIBLE_SSH_ARGS is that it appends your ssh config to whatever is on the system instead of totally overriding it.   Further, the SSH user cannot be specified in the args as Ansible decides who its SSHing as before getting to the ssh config (hence needing the -u flag or specifying it in ansible.cfg).  Issue #4622 is a won't fix, which I find crazy as it's surprising for Ansible to half-honor an SSH config.